Does calling a dependent function that has not been yet declared at the point of template definition cause the program to be IFNDR?
Assuming the use of the latest C++ standard, consider:
template<class T>
void foo(T t){ fuu<T>(); }

template<class T>
void fuu(){}

int main() {
  foo(5L);
}

LIVE
Is this program IFNDR or just ill-formed? I would appreciate if I can get a walkthrough of what the standard says here.
I tried reading the relevant paragraphs myself but I'm still not completely sure. It looks IFNDR according to [temp.dep.candidate]... at least from my understanding.
The reason I'm wondering is because GCC and clang output an error, while MSVC doesn't (even by using the /permissive- flag), and I want to know whether the latter is compliant.
Here is the gcc error, for instance:

error: there are no arguments to 'fuu' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'fuu' must be available [-fpermissive]


That changes nothing.

The flag is /permissive-, not /permissive. You may edit your question if you are really using the correct flag.

Thanks, that was a typo on the question.

Possibly temp.res 6: "The validity of a templated entity may be checked prior to any instantiation." Since there is no visible declaration for fuu, it presumably fails the validity test. (Note that in your example, fuu<T> could be either a type or a function!)

Which is the latest standard? Few years from now this would be a different question

I'm not sure, but is the fuu in the function template definition actually dependent? I would think that it is not. The name depends on nothing, so it is looked up immediately and is not found.

@RaymondChen I also read that one but still wasn't sure. The first point seems to be this case, if I'm not mistaken?

I think I found it. The definition of a "dependent call" is postfix-expression (expression-list[opt]), and a postfix-expression is an unqualified-id, and the type of unqualified-id in this case wants to be a simple-template-id, but a simple-template-id must be headed by  template-name, and fuu is not a template-name since it is as-yet undeclared. And temp.res 6 rule permits a compiler to validate at declaration time, so both behaviors are correct. gcc and clang validate early. msvc validates late.

Furthermore gcc's error message is correct but misleading. The name fuu<T> is not dependent, but it could be made dependent if you had template-dependent arguments, because that would trigger argument dependent lookup, which must occur late.

So basically if fuu took (T t), then the call fuu(t) would be dependent? And indeed, MSVC shows an error for that case

Edit: Corrected inaccuracies after Richard Smith pointed out that I have misread the words.
Since C++20, function calls where the function is named by an unqualified template-id have been able to participate in argument-dependent lookup. However, contrary to what I said earlier, the explicitly specified template arguments for the function don't contribute to the associated entities set of associated entities.
Note that [temp.dep.general]/2 says that if such a template argument is dependent, the call is considered a dependent call:

A dependent call is an expression, possibly formed as a non-member candidate for an operator ([over.match.oper]), of the form:

[...]
the unqualified-id is a template-id in which any of the template arguments depends on a template parameter.

[...]

Since it's a dependent call, [basic.lookup.argdep]/4 applies:

The associated namespaces for a call are the innermost enclosing non-inline namespaces for its associated entities as well as every element of the inline namespace set ([namespace.def]) of those namespaces. Argument-dependent lookup finds all declarations of functions and function templates that

are found by a search of any associated namespace, or
are declared as a friend ([class.friend]) of any class with a reachable definition in the set of associated entities, or
are exported, are attached to a named module M ([module.interface]), do not appear in the translation unit containing the point of the lookup, and have the same innermost enclosing non-inline namespace scope as a declaration of an associated entity attached to M ([basic.link]).

If the lookup is for a dependent name ([temp.dep], [temp.dep.candidate]), the above lookup is also performed from each point in the instantiation context ([module.context]) of the lookup, additionally ignoring any declaration that appears in another translation unit, is attached to the global module, and is either discarded ([module.global.frag]) or has internal linkage.

This leads to a strange situation where fuu<T>() is considered a dependent call (because T is a template parameter of the enclosing function) and is therefore subject to the rule above, but the ADL can't find the fuu declared after foo because there are no associated namespaces for the call (and therefore, there is nothing to search). The "second phase" of the name lookup, which uses ADL, is ineffective.
Therefore, it appears that the definition of foo is ill-formed, no diagnostic required: no valid specialization can be generated by foo because when the second phase of name lookup is done, it will always turn out that name lookup for fuu has failed since no declarations after foo will be found. See [temp.res.general]/6.1. But once you have an actual instantiation of foo, as in the OP's program, a diagnostic becomes required (note that [temp.res.general]/6.1 has "and the innermost enclosing template is not instantiated" as a condition).
Note: It's been argued in the comments to the question that fuu<T> fails to be a valid template-id because fuu hasn't yet been introduced as a template-name. However, if this argument were correct, it would imply that many dependent calls would be syntactically invalid because the identifier that names the function would fail to be an id-expression; see [expr.post], [expr.prim.grammar], [expr.prim.id.unqual]/1. I think the intent of the standard is to treat fuu as a template-name in this context.

Thanks for the reply. According to other messages, foo is not a dependent call. Therefore all of this would apply if it was. Could you please confirm?

@KTKT I've added a section to my answer that discusses this.

Thanks. I'll accept this answer. One last question that still seems unanswered (I think): is this just ill-formed, or IFNDR? Because if it's just ill-formed, then MSVC has a bug here. Thanks for the detailed reply once again, quite appreciated!

I think EDG is wrong: ADL doesn't look in associated namespaces of template arguments in the function name, only in associated namespaces of the call arguments, so N::fuu shouldn't be found here.

@KTKT It's required to be diagnosed because name lookup can't find fuu.

@RichardSmith Ah, I see, I have misread the words. Oops.

@RichardSmith But this is really strange. Why do we say it's a dependent call in this case if the second phase of name lookup can't actually find anything that wasn't found in the first phase?
